# undefined element in array of array of type

Tags: typescript

I have an array of users of type `User = { id: number; name: string; floor: number }`, where `floor: number` is a floor in the company where given user is working.
I want to create an array `building` of N floors (number is constant), and every `building[i]` must contain a list of users (an array of `User`).

So it should look like this:

```
building = [
    1: [ [11, bob, 1], [42, jane, 1], [33, tom, 1] ],
    2: [ [14, amir, 2], [35, isaac, 2] ],
    ...
    N: [ [62, jack, N], [93, tobby, N], [21, elisa, N] ],
]
```

I try to implement idea in the next code:

```
type User = { id: number; name: string; floor: number }
building: Array<User[]>;
foo() {
    this.building = new Array<User[]>(3);
    ...
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if ( users[i].floor ) {
            this.building[users[i].floor].push(users[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run code there is an error: `core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

What I missing?

Comment: you are not initializing your inner array you are just declaring something.

Comment: `this.building = new Array<User[]>(3);` does not create an array with three `User[]` arrays in it. It creates an array with three empty slots in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the arrays within the first array before you can push elements, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    type User = { id: number; name: string; floor: number }
    building: Array<User[]>;

    foo() {
        this.building = new Array<User[]>(3);
        // ...
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].floor) {

                // Create the array if not already existing
                this.building[users[i].floor] ||= [];
                this.building[users[i].floor].push(users[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```